# Finding linearly interdependent columns of a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Problem: I have an MxN matrix where M>=N.  I want to identify the groups of linearly-interdependent column-vectors within this matrix.

I'm hoping there's a fast and easy way to do this in numpy.

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(7, 6)
>>> a[:, 3] = 2*a[:, 0]-a[:, 4]
>>> a[:, 5] = 3*a[:, 1]
```

I'm looking for a function get_column_groups, which will return

```
>>> get_column_groups(a)
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1])
```

I guess bonus points if it also returns the rank of each group, e.g.:

```
>>> groups, group_ranks = get_column_groups(a)
>>> groups    
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1])
>>> group_ranks
[2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly and am wondering to what extent it is well-defined, because I am not sure these groups are unique. Below I have given an answer based on the Spark of the matrix.

Comment: Maybe your problem is more specific than this and can be better solved with additional information?

Comment: My intuition is that it's unique, but maybe my intuition is not generalizing to higher dimensions.  Picturing a 3-d space with 3 vectors, where a "group" of two of these vectors lie on a line that passes through the origin.  The 3rd, lonely vector can not be constructed as a linear combination of the vectors in the group of 2, but any vector in the group of 2 is a multiple of the other one.  So we'd have groups==[0, 0, 1] and group_ranks = [1, 1].  I can't picture a situation where a vector could belong to more than one group, but maybe that's because I can't picture 4-d.

Comment: Maybe my reasoning is only valid in matrices with M <= N, but if you imagine such a matrix to be in general position (wrt columns), then it will always take M + 1 vectors to make a linearly dependent combination, and any M + 1 vectors will suffice to do this.

Comment: But this should generalize to your case, as follows: If your matrix with M > N is rank deficient (if it isn't then you have your solution, because all columns are linearly independent), then you can map its image back to a subspace of R^N isomorphically. Concatenating the two operations would not lose information and you would be working with a matrix of less lines than columns.

Comment: Suppose R is the rank of the MxN matrix with M>=N.  R<=N.  You can project isomorphically down to an RxN matrix.  It is true that any R+1 columns form a linearly dependent combination, but it is not true that any column in this matrix can always be constructed by the others, because the others can be linearly dependent.

Comment: e.g. 3x3 matrix with with columns 2 and 3 collinear.
can be projected isomorphically to a 2x3 matrix of rank 2. 
The 3 columns are linearly dependent, because col 2 and col 3 are, but column 1 cannot be constructed by 2 and 3.

Comment: You are right (+1 for comment) and I didn't say this isn't possible. I was talking about matrices in *general position* when I made this (trivially true by definition) claim. In my next comment, all I did was show the equivalence of your problem with rank deficient `M > N`  matrix to one with an `R < N` matrix. Once this is established, I think one can conclude that the problem is at least as difficult as calculating the Spark, which is the claim in my answer.

Comment: (If your M < N matrix is in general position, that means that all combinations of M columns will be linearly independent and all combinations of M + 1 columns will be linearly dependent. Thus the groups you are looking for wouldn't be well defined.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, computing the [Spark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_(mathematics)) of the matrix is a subproblem of what you are requesting, hence rendering it NP-Complete in most cases.

There may be some algorithms that do this better than just combinatorial evaluation of columns up to a size of `rank(a)`, but this would be a start.

Comment: [Here](http://puzlet.com/m/b0086) is an octave implementation that could serve as a starting point.

Comment: Hmm.  Yes, so I guess the dumb method is

Comment: The spark identifies the dimension of the lowest dimensional group, but not the columns that define it.  I guess I need argspark.  Then you could just remove these columns iteratevely to to get the groups.

Comment: Dumb method would be take every possible combination of columns, and get the rank of the submatrix composed of each combination, then assign each column to the lowest ranking combination that it belonged to.  I think that'd work.

Comment: I pointed out Spark to show that the problem is difficult. As you say, the first group you are looking for would be in argSpark.